# In Rails, can the options in a select field be edited like a text field?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a problem on my application.

I have collection select code

```
<% baskets.each do |f| %> 
    <%= f.select :link, @books.collect{|x| [x.title, x.id]}.unshift(['Please select','']) %>
<% end %>
```

How do I make the select option editable like a text field so that I can copy and paste the link to choose from the book collections?

I've never tried this. Do you have any suggestion?

Thanks for your help :)

Comment: Kuya, I have edited your question to try to make it clearer. I hope it still matches what you were looking for.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using a select field you could use a text field with [auto complete](http://github.com/rails/auto_complete).

Comment: but they won't used auto complete, i have used this for the tag

Comment: What do you mean they won't use auto complete? Do you want a drop down list in which the value can also be edited?